# In VHDL what is a data operator type "variable" when it is translated to circuit?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, synthesis, data-operator

VHDL code is finally converted into hardware equivalent when it is synthesized. What happens to data operator type "variable" when it is synthesized?

Comment: The question is not identical, it isn't coherent, a language definition issue. A variable is one of four object classes (signal, constant, variable and file. A synthesis eligible object's value can be any declared type and is represented post synthesis as binary values. While meta values can imply functionality ('Z' implying tristate) only logical values ('0','1') are used to verify net list object equivalence. See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 6.4 Object and 1076.6-2004, 5. Verification methodology. Syntax/semantics imply circuitry.

Answer (score 0):

Variables may or may not represent physical wires.
Variable assignments are order dependent
Variable assignment under a clocked process may or may not be translated into registers.
I also have examples.

CASE 1 : variable temp
process (clk)
If (clk’event and clk = ‘1’)  then 
   temp  := a and b; 
   y <= c and temp;
end if; 
end process;

CASE 2 : variable temp
process (clk)
If (clk’event and clk = ‘1’) then 
    y <= c and temp;
    temp  := a and b; 
end if;
end process;

both cases create different hardware.